# Do varieties with ample canonical bundle have finite automorphism group in small characteristic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p, automorphism-groups

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective variety over a field $k$, with ample canonical bundle.  If $\operatorname{char}(k)=0$ or $\operatorname{char}(k)>\dim(X)$ and $X$ lifts to $W_2(k)$ (thanks Olivier Benoist!), it's not hard to see that $X$ has finite automorphism group.

**Proof.**  Let $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}\Gamma(X, \omega_X^{\otimes n})^\vee$ be a closed embedding.  Then the induced map $\operatorname{Aut}(X)\hookrightarrow PGL(\Gamma(X, \omega_X^{\otimes n})^\vee)$ is a closed embedding, so $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is finite type.  But the tangent space to $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ at the identity is $\Gamma(X, T_X)$, which is trivial by Kodaira vanishing.  So $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is a $0$-dimensional finite type group scheme, hence finite. $\blacksquare$

(An essentially identical argument avoiding the representability of $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ may be found [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~dlitt/briefnotes/notes/curve-automorphisms.pdf).)

This proof breaks down for $\operatorname{char}(k)$ small:  $\Gamma(X, T_X)$ need not be trivial.  But I don't know of an example of a canonically polarized variety with infinite (thus necessarily positive-dimensional) automorphism group in small characteristic.

> Is the automorphism group of a smooth variety with ample canonical bundle always finite, even if $\operatorname{char}(k)$ is small?

Comment: How do you know that the map ${\rm{Aut}}_{X/k} \rightarrow {\rm{PGL}}(\Gamma(X,\omega^{\otimes n})^{\vee})$ has closed image (e.g., why is it finite type?)? It is certainly not sufficient that it has trivial kernel.  One can make plenty of maps from a locally finite type $k$-group to a finite type $k$-group with trivial kernel.

Comment: The proof in your link is also flawed; why should $v$ there have anything to do with infinitesimal automorphisms of $X$ if it does not arise from the tangent space to the automorphism scheme (but just that of the closure of its image)?

Comment: @user76758 : no it is OK : consider the closed subgroup scheme $G\subset PGL_{N+1}$ consisting of automorphisms preserving $X$. There are natural morphisms of group schemes in both directions : $G\to Aut(X)$ by restricting the action to $X$, and $Aut(X)\to G$ using the induced action on pluricanonical forms. Using the fact that $X\to\mathbb{P}^N$ is an embedding, you can see that these two maps are inverse to each other.

Comment: @DanielLitt : I am worried about your statement that you will be able to apply Kodaira vanishing if $p>dim(X)$. Are you sure you're not mistaken ?

Comment: @OlivierBenoist:  I have in mind the proof of Kodaira vanishing in Deligne-Illusie.  I think this works given the restriction on the characteristic I've stated.

Comment: @DanielLitt : to apply Deligne-Illusie, you also need to know that $X$ lifts to the second Witt vectors of $k$.

Comment: @OlivierBenoist: Ah, of course you're right.  Oops.

Comment: @user76758: Olivier Benoist addresses your first complaint--as for the second, there's an induced action of v via the action on projective space.  (In fact, I guess the fact that the closure of the image of $Aut(X)$ acts on $X$ via its action on projective space answers both objections.)

Comment: OK, good to see what I was overlooking.

Comment: @user76758:  No worries--it's good to make this explicit.  Maybe I'll add a remark on this to the linked pdf.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A much more general result is proven in [Martin-Deschamps, Lewin-Menegaux : Applications rationnelles séparables dominantes sur une variété de type général](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1978__106_/BSMF_1978__106__279_0/BSMF_1978__106__279_0.pdf). Théorème 2 : if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth and proper, and if $Y$ is of general type, the set of dominant separable rational maps from $X$ to $Y$ is finite !
  What you want follows immediately: it is their Corollaire 4, and they attribute it to Matsumura.

Comment: Perfect!  I'd seen Kobayashi's analytic argument for this over $\mathbb{C}$, but hadn't been able to find an algebraic argument.